# Proving self-consistency of sets of postulates e.g. for spatial Poisson point process

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation, point-processes

Suppose you have a list of postulates/properties P1, P2, P3 etc. that you would like a (possibly not yet defined) mathematical object to satisfy. Is it possible to prove that the properties P1, P2, etc. are self-consistent *without* explicitly constructing a mathematical object satisfying the required properties?

The reason for asking this is that I am currently looking at ways of defining the homogenous spatial Poisson point process on (a sub region of) $\mathbb{R}^2$. I am aware of explicit constructions of this process. However, Diggle's book on "Statistical Analysis of Spatial and Spatio-temporal Point Patterns" avoids these constructions and instead starts from two postulates, called PP1 and PP2. PP1 states that, for some $\lambda>0$ and for any planar region $A$, the number of points in $A$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$ (i.e. $N(A)\sim Po(\lambda)$. PP2 states that, given $N(A)=n$, the points in $A$ form an independent random sample from the uniform distribution on $A$.

The text goes on to demonstrate "self-consistency" of PP1 and PP2 (pages 61-62 in the third edition)...

[image]

[image]

This is done by first showing that PP1 and PP2 together imply PP3, which states that for disjoint regions $A$ and $B$, $N(A)$ and $N(B)$ are independent. Then various arguments are given, the substance of which is something like "if PP2 holds for $A$ then it also holds for any subregion of $A$" and "if PP1 and PP2 hold for disjoint $A$ and $B$ then they also hold for $A\cup B$". I don't see how such an argument, with no explicit construction of the point process, can show that PP1 and PP2 are self-consistent. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: It's not too difficult to explicitly construct a process $(N_A)_{A \in \mathcal B_{\mathbb{R}^2}}$ which satisfies PP1 and PP3, using the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem. In fact I think that such a construction would work for any measure space, not just $\Bbb R^2$ with Lebesgue measure. The crucial fact is that the sum of independent Poissons is itself Poisson with sum of the individual parameters. I could go into detail about it, but Diggle's approach is likely more understandable.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks for your comments. Generally Diggle's book is very well written, but this section seems quite tricky to understand! An explicit construction seems more straightforward to me. Regarding PP1, I think it is correct, as in this case I am dealing with the *homogenous* Poisson point process, which has constant (in space) intensity $\lambda$. For the inhomogenous Poisson point process, PP3 would state that $N(A)$ and $N(B)$ are conditionally independent, given the spatial intensity function $\lambda (s)$.